# attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form validation with ajax and jquery. I've done this before but now it seems to be failing over and over.

The title is the error I see in the firebug console. After some google research, seems to be a problem with managing windows but... I'm not trying to do that and I also tried in other browsers with identical results. The form submits...

This is the function:

```
$("#login-da").submit(function(){
        $('#error').hide();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val(); 
        var query = 'username=' + username + '&pass=' + password;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/check-user.php",
            async: false,
            data: query,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                        if(response == 0) {                         
                            $('#error').slideDown();
                            var error = 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            var error = 0;
                        }
                    }
        });
        if (error == 1){        
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've tried to return false directly in the success function with identical results. The error begins to show but the form submits anyways and nothing appear.
I've also noticed through debugging that anything outside the ajax call isn't executed.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What are you returning from the check-user.php script? You should be able to see what comes back in the Net tab of Firebug.

Comment: 0 or 1. I've checked because I also call to this file to check if the user exists on field update and worked.

Comment: Is it only in Firefox that you get an error? Probably you have already read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433415/error-attempt-to-run-compile-and-go-script-on-a-cleared-scope

Comment: Yes I did! And, as I state in the post, I've tried with other browsers with no results :(

Comment: Asking once again: what are you returning from the check-user.php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Number() on the response data, also, check the scope of the error variable on the response funcion:

```
success: function (response) {
    var result = Number(response);
    if (result == 0) {
        $('#error').slideDown();
        error = 1;
    } else {
        error = 0;
    }
}
```