# jQuery Animation error = attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I hope someone can help with this. I've got a strange error coming up in Firebug on my page.

I'm using the code:

```
$(function () {
var element = $("#finger");
(function(){
    element
        .animate({ marginLeft: 130 }, 1000)
        .animate({ marginLeft: 100 },   1000 , arguments.callee);
}());
});
```

This works fine to animate my 'finger'.

I also have this other code:

```
$("SOME-OTHER-DIV").mousedown(function () { 
  $("#finger").hide(); 
});
```

This makes my 'finger' hide when clicked on.

Now, this all works fine.... up until the point when I reload the page whereby I get this error

"attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope"

Yet, the animation still works, and the mousedown also still works.

Any ideas what's going on here? Is it just a bug in Firefox?
Many thanks in advance
Chris

----------update---------

Hmm, perhaps it's not the "arguments.callee" that's causing the problem. I changed the code to:

```
$(function () {
i = 0;
while(i < 3){
$("#finger").animate({ marginLeft: 130 }, 1000).animate({ marginLeft: 100 },   1000);
i++;
}
});
```

Which loops through 3 times (ok, not infinite, but it's just for example) and I still get the "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" error on page reload in Firebug :-S

Comment: I like the animation [lol](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7CC/) and once you are on that page, click back(in IE8). :P

Comment: Thankfully with this project I don't need to support IE \o/

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with FF4. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433415/error-attempt-to-run-compile-and-go-script-on-a-cleared-scope) and [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635548). As the other thread says try clearing the cache.

Try this code and check if you still get the error - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7CC/3/)

```
$(function() {
    animateFinger();
});

$("#abc").mousedown(function() {
    $("#finger").toggle("display");
});

function animateFinger() {
    $("#finger").animate({
        marginLeft: 130
    }, 1000).animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 1000, animateFinger);
}
```

---

If that doesn't work try using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and calling the method every 2000 milliseconds - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7CC/4/)

```
$(function() {
    animateFinger();
    setInterval(animateFinger, 2000);
    // You can also try function(){setTimeout(animateFinger, 0)} as a callback method instead of setInterval
});

$("#abc").mousedown(function() {
    $("#finger").toggle("display");
});

function animateFinger() {
    $("#finger").animate({
        marginLeft: 130
    }, 1000).animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 1000);
}
```

All the best in your finger pointing business. ;)

Comment: Thanks for this code, absolutely awesome. Works a treat for animating the finger indefinitely. However after having tried all these options I am sorry to have to say that it still produces the same error on reload.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `arguments.callee` may be the cause.  I think that does some funky trickery that not all JS engines fully support.

Comment: Yes seems to be "arguments.callee" that's causing the problem. Is there any other way of looping this animation without using "arguments.callee"?

Answer (score -3):

It's Firefox. If you disable the cache the error probably won't pop up.

In about:config set:

```
network.http.use-cache = false
```

Comment: Not really helpful. Asking users to disable the cache would be unacceptable.