# attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

Tags: jquery, iframe, console

I have a function that create an `iframe` in the page:

```
var wrapper = outer_doc.find('#wrapper');
create('iframe_sub', url + 'pages/page.html', '565px', '466px');
$('<div class="submenu" ></div>').appendTo(wrapper).append(ifrm);
```

another function change the source of the `iframe`:

```
outer_doc.find("#iframe_sub").attr('src',menu_item).
```

on the second function I get this error on firebug console on firefox 5.0:

**attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope**

```
@ jquery.1.6.1.js (line 16)
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache.  That seemed to be the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433415/error-attempt-to-run-compile-and-go-script-on-a-cleared-scope) with the bug listed [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635548).

Comment: Did you read the links?  From what I understand it is a bug in FF4

Comment: i use ff 5 and it's still there

Comment: Hmm one of the solutions listed was to add <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />. I am not sure if that will fix your issue since this is a bug in FF.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem a few times. It has always been because of an action being performed within `$(document).ready`. Most recently the actions were with `google.load` for maps and for other api's. If you are using google services then be sure they are loading before the document is ready I guess, but initialized after the DOM is available.