# How can I create JS event listeners that survive a document.write?

Tags: javascript, events, document.write

I'm attaching an event listener to the window object. Then later in the script, document.write is being used. (I know, it's evil. I have no choice in the matter.) The problem is, the document.write wipes out my listeners. Is is possible to avoid that?

Here's a fiddle that illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Fuhzu/

Comment: No choice? Can't use div id=me me.innerHTML = "hah"? Or hah = document.createElement(span) me.appendChild(hah)?

Comment: No -- I have to work with some other existing code. It's possible that that could someday be changed, but not immediately.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. `document.write` unloads the current document, and creates a new one.

A demo to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/Gk3cX/

```
window.test = document; //Cache document
document.write('<button onclick="alert(window.test===document)">CLick</button>');
// Clicking shows false! The document has changed!
```

Your only choice for overwriting the current document without unloading is `innerHTML`:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Overwritten document's content, kept events.";
```

Answer (score 2):

The work-around I've found is to simply re-attach the listeners after the document.write.

**Update**: Doh! That works in Chrome, but FF throws an error:

```
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYyKH/

Maybe if I unattach the handler before document.writing....

**Update 2**: nope: http://jsfiddle.net/sprugman/KzNbX/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing `document.write` with your own function, that way it won't destroy the page.

Something like this:

```
document.write = function(str){
    document.body.innerHTML = str;
};
```

Or if you don't want to erase the whole page:

```
document.write = function(str){
    document.body.innerHTML += str;
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Fuhzu/1/

Comment: Easier said than done when your script is part of an ad chain which calls more scripts which may or may not have document.write in them.

Comment: @sprugman: What if you declare this at the top of your page, before those scripts are ran?

Comment: I don't have control of the page. I'm creating a script that other people embed in their pages, and there are many, many possible embedding situations, so overwriting document.write could easily break something without my knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried this with document.write, but maybe it helps:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future